# Create a filter in tableau that only shows those which meets both conditions in a single dimension

Tags: tableau-desktop

A beginner at Tableau trying to make one of my first simple visualizations.
I have a simple dataset with IDs and a simple yes/no. Example table as shown below:

| ID | Parameter |
| --- | --- |
| A | Yes |
| A | No |
| B | Yes |
| C | No |

I would like to create a filter that only shows those ID where the parameters have both yes and no. I have been trying to filter by creating calculated fields but they don't work across rows.
The expected result is to show only A as A is the only ID with both Yes and No Parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to use a calculated field:

```
IF{FIXED ID:COUNTD(YN)}=2 THEN TRUE  
ELSE FALSE  
END
```